# Modal Progress Dialog - How to pass in delegate?

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0

I have a basic form with a progress bar and want to pass in a delegate of sorts like this:

```
ProgressDialog.ShowAndExecute(delegate);
```

I can't figure out how to connect the delegate to progress messages.

```
void ShowAndExecute()
{
    // Handle form disabling and whatnot...

    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteCommand));

    while (thread.IsAlive)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}

// Example of the method I would like to pass in
void ExecuteCommand()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

I thought about creating an interface that the commands should implement. They can fire an event whenever an update occurs, but how do I let the calling thread know it was fired?

How do you handle passing in delegates that report progress through events and act (move progress bar) based on those? This is a static dialog (to make it easier to call throughout the app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the `ExecuteCommand` knows its current progress. So some interface or class must be passed to the `ExecuteCommand` method. The `ExecuteCommand` will set the progress, then it's up to the implementation of the listener to determine what to do with the progress. In general, the listener will check if it's a significant change** in progress, and if so, it will `BeginInvoke` a call to update a progress bar.

** - If you process thousands of items in a short period of time, then you want to protect against calling `BeginInvoke` too much, otherwise it will lock up the UI thread.

```
void ExecuteCommand(IThreadController tc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        tc.setProgress("processing ...", (i+1), 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got me where I needed to go. Thanks!